# use case for Double as HashMap Keys

Tags: java, hashmap, double

I am just going through my notes where I have `Doubles` as `HashMap` keys are bad that I vaguely remember using it for some online coding platform.

Are there any use cases and alternatives in dealing with `Double` as Keys which you have dealt with in real world or interviews or coding problems?

I was thinking of the following, in case of an interview I can argue to use this and make my argument this is the best we can do.?

```
MyDouble(){
   private final double original;
   private final long value;

   public MyDouble(double original) {
      this.original = original;
      this.value = Double.doubleToLongBits(original);
   }
}
```

Comment: You can do this as long as you implement your own wrapper that implements `equals()` and `hashCode()` in a manner that satisfies your requirements.  Internal conversion to big decimal or string with a fixed precision is one possibility.  This is not a hard problem if you clearly understand the limitations and the tradeoffs in how you program around them.

Comment: great. make sense i can work around the equals issue based on the problem statement.